# when disc is full the web service dont respond

Tags: java, spring, web-services, hibernate, jakarta-ee

i have a web service, it create an image for a captcha, it send and image to another server
in bytes, then this server ( the receiver ), create an image with that bytes, and then render the image with an action of struts2.

i've noted that when the log is full, ( when i dont have space in disk ),the web service is not sending the bytes of the captcha, why i say this, because, after delete the logs and free some space of the web service, it works normaly, but i dont know why its happening

im using:

Struts2
spring
hibernate
the web service its RESTFUL

i hope, i explain myself

Comment: Which logging system are you using?  When are you logging during these steps?

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion:
In general, i would expect some kind of exception (which describes the error), when Server does not respond.
Anyway, when your HardDisc is full (so **nothing** can be written to it), the request (or response) may fail, because it cannot create temporary image **file** for the captcha?

**EDIT**:
Keep in mind that an **FULL HARD DISK** can **always** result in strange **system** behaviour!
Maybe any **system process/request** (which is internally used by JAVA) fails when your HD is full.
 And this will result into not sending the response.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, the logging could also be throwing an exception causing it to fail.

Comment: thanks both of you, that was the error we are looking for a tool to mange logs